# Flutter Bottomsheet Modal not rerendering

Tags: dart, flutter

On my grid items when I click, it opens a `ModalBottomSheet` and listed with filter chips of strings. When you click a filter chip value, the value is updated but the widget does not re-render. The app is a `StatefulWidget`.

I have called the function `setState`.

What I expect is filterchips becomes checked and unchecked on selection.

```
void _showBottom(index){
    showModalBottomSheet<void>(
        context: context,

        builder: (BuildContext context){
          return new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(27.0),
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[                
                new Text('Some headline', style: new TextStyle(  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 22),),
                getFilterChipsWidgets(index),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }


Widget getFilterChipsWidgets(index)
  {
    List<Widget> tags_list = new List<Widget>();
      for(var i=0; i<list[index]["tags"].length; i++) {       
        var _isSelected = true;

        FilterChip item = new FilterChip(
          label: Text("Filtertext",), 
          selected: _isSelected,
          onSelected: (bool newValue) {            
            setState(() {
              _isSelected = !_isSelected;
              debugPrint(_isSelected.toString());
            });
          },
        );
        tags_list.add(item);       
      }
      return new Row(children: tags_list);
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add height for the root node of the bottom sheet. So change your container to have a fixed height.

```
 Container(
     height: 300.0, // Add height
     padding: new EdgeInsets.all(27.0),
     child: new Column(
       children: <Widget>[                
          new Text('Some headline', 
               style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 22),),
                getFilterChipsWidgets(index),
              ],
            ),
```

I usually calculate this dynamically based on the widgets I'm passing in. But this should get you started.

**Edit**

The comment I gave below was the actual answer.

You should wrap all the widgets in the bottom sheet into it's own stateful widget and set your values in there.

Comment: @Mark sorry about that I read your question completely wrong. The edits have helped my see that now. The modal value will not re-render while on the screen, it has to be closed and re-opened. You should wrap all the widgets in the bottom sheet into it's own stateful widget and set your values in there. I think that should solve it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked by wrap all the widgets in the bottom sheet into it's own stateful widget!

Comment: @Mark awesome. I'll edit the answer and then you can accept it

Answer (score 0):

Modal Bottom sheet seems to call the constructor whenever any change in the UI occurs in the child widget for example changing focus inside a form.

So you need to create instances of the objects you are working with inside a parent **StatefulWidget** and then to reflect changes in the UI of the Model Bottom Sheet you need to call setState whenever you make changes to the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the under `StatefulBuilder` like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void _showBottom(index){
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  context: context,

  builder: (BuildContext context){
    return StatefulBuilder( builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState){
      return new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(27.0),
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text('Some headline', style: new TextStyle(  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 22),),
            getFilterChipsWidgets(index, setState),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
);}


Widget getFilterChipsWidgets(index, StateSetter setState)
{
 List<Widget> tags_list = new List<Widget>();
 for(var i=0; i<list[index]["tags"].length; i++) {
 var _isSelected = true;

  FilterChip item = new FilterChip(
  label: Text("Filtertext",),
  selected: _isSelected,
  onSelected: (bool newValue) {
    setState(() {
      _isSelected = !_isSelected;
      debugPrint(_isSelected.toString());
    });
  },
);
tags_list.add(item);
}
return new Row(children: tags_list);
}
```